# Timeseries resample to guarantee constant inverval

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a timeseries such as:

```
date                   value
08/08/2012 08:00:00    0.94843
08/08/2012 08:05:00    0.92313
08/08/2012 08:06:21    0.90432 
08/08/2012 08:10:10    0.99192 
08/08/2012 08:15:00    0.91233 
08/08/2012 08:17:37    0.94841
08/08/2012 08:34:19    0.91221
```

And I want to resample to create fixed 5 minutes periods that start at the 1st event time, output:

```
date                   value
08/08/2012 08:00:00    0.94843
08/08/2012 08:05:00    0.92313
08/08/2012 08:10:00    0.99192 
08/08/2012 08:15:00    0.91233 
08/08/2012 08:20:00    0.94841
08/08/2012 08:25:00    0.94841
08/08/2012 08:30:00    0.94841
08/08/2012 08:35:00    0.91221
```

OR (also acceptable)

```
date                   value
08/08/2012 08:00:00    0.94843
08/08/2012 08:05:00    0.92313
08/08/2012 08:10:00    0.99192 
08/08/2012 08:15:00    0.91233 
08/08/2012 08:20:00    0.94841
08/08/2012 08:35:00    0.91221
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also could you elaborate more on your logic?   As far as I can see `08:10:10`'s value is resampled to `08:10:00` (backward), and `08:34:19`'s value is resampled to `08:35:00` (forward), it is inconsistent.  you are discarding `08:06:21`'s value, so it is not picking the `nearest` value either.

Answer (score 0):

Original Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['08/08/2012 08:00:00', '08/08/2012 08:05:00',
                            '08/08/2012 08:06:21', '08/08/2012 08:10:10',
                            '08/08/2012 08:15:00',  '08/08/2012 08:17:37',
                            '08/08/2012 08:34:19'],
 'value': [0.94843, 0.92313, 0.90432, 0.99192, 0.91233, 0.94841, 0.91221]})
```

Converting `date` column into date format

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Extracting seconds from `date` column

```
df = df.assign(second = df['date'].dt.second)
```

Creating a column `flag` which tells if `seconds` are multiple of 5 or not.
In place of `1` you can put random number & then extract rows based on that random number.

```
df['flag'] =df['second'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x%5==0 else 0)
```

Filter based on `flag` column value. I didn't drop other columns for exposition purpose.

```
df1 = df[df['flag'] == 1]
print(df1)
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for the 1st output?

Comment: The output of `df1` is the 1st output you asked in the question.